# What is the difference between QTP 9.0 and 9.2? What is the difference of automated testing in financial and telecom clients?

Tags: qtp

What is the difference between QTP 9.0 and 9.2? What is the difference of automated testing in financial and telecom clients?

Comment: You've got 2 questions rolled into one here, any neither are specific enough to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that QTP 9.2 is ancient and QTP 9.0 is *way* ancient.

As of 2011 QTP 11 is available.